# How to show popUp with opening/closing effects when selecting UIBarButtonItem from NavigationBar in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios14

[image]

> **Is this any Default Property in updated iOS14 or is it made in `SwiftUI` or is it a custom `UIView`?**

- If it is Default Property, then how to use it ? (is it available in
  `Apple Documentation`)
- If it is in `SwiftUI` , How to use this property in `Swift5` ?
- If it is a Custom `UIView`, then How can I
  create one with opening and closing animation effects (if you have
  iPhone running iOS 14+, then you can see the animation effects when
  it opens or closes , it's like a Scaling Animation I guess) ???

Thanks

Comment: i'm also find solution for this tricky question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new feature in iOS14 (UIKit and swiftUI) called pulldown menu or context menu. Menu can now added to UIButtons and UIBarbuttonItems.

```
let tbMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: /* UIActions */)
UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "list.number"), menu: buttonMenu)
```

[Pull-down menus](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/)
[Context menus](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/context-menus/) (for TableViews)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good cocoa pod for this [Dropdown](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DropDown)

Its working is also very simple

creating dropdown

```
let dropDown = DropDown()
// The view to which the drop down will appear on
    dropDown.anchorView = view // UIView or UIBarButtonItem
// The list of items to display. Can be changed dynamically
    dropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]
```

Optional Action properties

```
// Action triggered on selection
dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
  print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
}

// Will set a custom width instead of the anchor view width
dropDownLeft.width = 200
```

Display Actions are

```
dropDown.show()
dropDown.hide()
```

You can also do very advance things like customise cell , display direction etc have a look at the [Documentation](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DropDown#advanced-usage-)

Comment: Yes @Abdul, I have also used `DropDown` but I wanted to know about the default feature which is in ios14+ devices....
Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: @NayanDave this might help you https://medium.com/better-programming/using-ios-14s-menu-as-a-picker-in-swiftui-b036c772037